# VBA: Finding max value of sum among continuous numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table which goes from A1 to ALL1 (1000 values), I have to find the max value of consecutive numbers for example if I had these six values:

4 37 -12 2 3 -1, the max would be 41 taken from the first two numbers. If it was

-6 -14 6 15 22 -9, it would be 43 (from 6, 15, 22).

I have to do this in VBA from randomly generated numbers (figured that part out so it's good), but can't figure out this part and then I have to return the position of the first and last value in my sequence. So please some help would be greatly appreciated as I'm not quite a VBA wizard.

Thank you :)

Comment: This is called the maximum sub-array problem, I've seen how to do it with arrays, but I'd really prefer doing it with VBA!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below example:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim arrValues() As Variant
    Dim dblTop As Double
    Dim lngFirst As Long
    Dim lngLast As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim dblSum As Double
    Dim arrResult() As Variant

    arrValues = Range("A1:ALL1")
    dblTop = arrValues(1, 1)
    lngFirst = 1
    lngLast = 1

    For i = 1 To 1000
        dblSum = 0
        For j = i To 1000
            dblSum = dblSum + arrValues(1, j)
            If dblSum > dblTop Then
                lngFirst = i
                lngLast = j
                dblTop = dblSum
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Debug.Print "Max value: " & dblTop
    Debug.Print "First index: " & lngFirst
    Debug.Print "Last index: " & lngLast
    arrResult() = Array()
    For k = lngFirst To lngLast
        ReDim Preserve arrResult(UBound(arrResult) + 1)
        arrResult(UBound(arrResult)) = arrValues(1, k)
    Next
    Debug.Print "Sequence: " & Join(arrResult, " + ")

End Sub
```

For the set of the values e. g. as in the question

[image: sheet1]

It returns the following output

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
Sub msa()
    Dim j&, cur&, max&, ndx&, ndx1&, ndx2&, a: ndx = 1
    a = [A1:ALL1]
    For j = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
        cur = cur + a(1, j)
        Select Case True
            Case cur > max:  max = cur:  ndx2 = j:  ndx1 = ndx
            Case cur <= 0:   cur = 0:    ndx = j + 1
        End Select
    Next
    MsgBox max & vbLf & ndx1 & vbLf & ndx2
End Sub
```

My answer is based on [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) which has a time complexity of O(n), which is dramatically more efficient than the brute force O(n*n) time complexity of the other answer.

.

**UPDATE**

To handle the edge case of all negative numbers as well, you can use this version:

```
Sub msa()
    Dim j&, k&, m&, n&, cur&, max&, ndx&, ndx1&, ndx2&, a: ndx = 1: m = -2 ^ 31
    a = [A1].CurrentRegion.Resize(1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
        k = a(1, j)
        If k > m Then m = k: n = j
        cur = cur + k
        Select Case True
            Case cur > max:  max = cur:  ndx2 = j:  ndx1 = ndx
            Case cur <= 0:   cur = 0:    ndx = j + 1
        End Select
    Next
    If max = 0 Then max = m: ndx1 = n: ndx2 = n
    MsgBox max & vbLf & ndx1 & vbLf & ndx2
End Sub
```

Comment: It's almost flawless! The only one thing is that it gives 0 when all numbers are negative.

Comment: You did not mention that you needed provision for the all negative case. I'll update...

Comment: @David Were you able to get this going?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be a little different, and because I did the work before my weekend blew up, here is a function that will return a range:

```
Function MAXSUM(r As Range) As Range
Dim i&, j&
Dim rng As Range
Dim sm As Double
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
sm = r.Item(1) + r.Item(2)
For i = 1 To r.Cells.Count - 1
    For j = i + 1 To r.Cells.Count
        With ws
            If WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(r(i), r(j))) > sm Then
                Set rng = .Range(r(i), r(j))
                sm = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(r(i), r(j)))
            End If
        End With
    Next j
Next i

Set MAXSUM = rng
```

The beauty of this is:

1.It returns the range of the max sum.

2.It is not dependent on being in the first row, it can be a column, a row, or multiples of each.  It will look left to right first then top to bottom of the range.

3.It can be called from vba and/or directly as a UDF in the worksheet(see below)

**To call from vba:**

```
Sub getmax()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set rng = MAXSUM(ws.Range("A1 :AAL1"))

Debug.Print rng.Address 'gets the address of range
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng) 'gets the sum of the range

End Sub
```

This just shows a few things, but because it returns a range it is possible to do anything one can do with a given range.

**To call from the worksheet directly:**

To get the sum:

```
=SUM(MAXSUM(*YourRange*))
```

*To get the range:*

First Cell:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(MAXSUM(*YourRange*)),COLUMN(MAXSUM(*YourRange*)))
```

Last cell:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(MAXSUM(*YourRange*))+ROWS(MAXSUM(*YourRange*))-1,COLUMN(MAXSUM(*YourRange*))+COLUMNS(MAXSUM(*YourRange*))-1)
```

Full Address:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(MAXSUM(*YourRange*)),COLUMN(MAXSUM(*YourRange*)))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(MAXSUM(*YourRange*))+ROWS(MAXSUM(*YourRange*))-1,COLUMN(MAXSUM(*YourRange*))+COLUMNS(MAXSUM(*YourRange*))-1)
```

Basically the formula `MAXSUM(*YourRange*)` works like a named range, and anything you can do with a named range you can do with this.

One note:  This currently assumes that the user wants the sum of at least two numbers and therefore if the entire range is negative, or only one consecutive positive it will return the sum of the two consecutive cells that give the highest sum.  To make it so it will return the highest one cell in the case of all negative or only one consecutive positive cells then remove the `+1` and `-1` from the beginning of the for loops.